# Parsing non-standard JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am receiving a non-standard JSON format from a request. How one can convert or parse this kind of non-standard format in JavaScript or any other scripting language?

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "sales": [
        {
            "id": 1195816,
            "city": "New York",
            "name": "testing1"
        },
        {
            "id": 1195815,
            "city": "LA",
            "name": "testing2"
        }
    ],
    "total_sales_count": 148393,
    "date": "17.04.2020"
}
{
    "count": 2,
    "sales": [
        {
            "id": 1195816,
            "city": "Washington",
            "name": "testing3"
        },
        {
            "id": 1195815,
            "city": "New Jersey",
            "name": "testing4"
        }
    ],
    "total_sales_count": 49403,
    "date": "17.04.2020"
}
```

Comment: What's non-standard exactly in the json?

Comment: Did you forget about the array that wraps these objects?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava The one that you can validate. Try this: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @sensahin Did you format these objects?  Surely each object itself is on its own line... otherwise, you'll have to use a streaming parser after all.

Comment: Ths is called a New-Line Delimited JSON https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122391/parsing-json-data-without-a-comma-separator/71684177#71684177

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have multiple JSON objects concatenated, separated with a newline.

A quick hack that might just work is to add a comma between the objects and wrap them in an array.

```
> JSON.parse(`[${json.replace(/\}\n\{/g, '},{')}]`);
(2) [{…}, {…}]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am receiving a non-standard JSON...

In fact, there is a standard.  Line-delimited, or ND-JSON.  http://ndjson.org/

It's desirable to use this format when returning multiple records.  It allows you to stream the response, and parse without having to load the entire dataset into memory at the same time.

To parse in JavaScript, I'd pick up one of the several standard packages available for this.  For example:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ndjson

```
fs.createReadStream('data.txt')
  .pipe(ndjson.parse())
  .on('data', function(obj) {
    // obj is a javascript object
  })
```

If you want to do this in a browser that supports transform streams, here's some code from one of my projects you can adapt:

```
return res.body
    // Decode as UTF-8 Text
    .pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream())

    // Split on lines
    .pipeThrough(new TransformStream({
      transform(chunk, controller) {
        textBuffer += chunk;
        const lines = textBuffer.split('\n');
        for (const line of lines.slice(0, -1)) {
          controller.enqueue(line);
        }
        textBuffer = lines.slice(-1)[0];
      },
      flush(controller) {
        if (textBuffer) {
          controller.enqueue(textBuffer);
        }
      }
    }))

    // Parse JSON objects
    .pipeThrough(new TransformStream({
      transform(line, controller) {
        if (line) {
          controller.enqueue(JSON.parse(line));
        }
      }
    }));
```

Comment: This might not work since OP's data isn't strictly one-JSON-object-per-line (but one-object-per-many-lines).

Comment: @AKX Ah, I assumed he formatted them for the question.  Good point.